# Change SSH port 22 to 800

Tags: ssh, ufw

A very simple question which I can't seem to find an answer for while googling.

I have changed the standard SSH port from 22 to 800. I added 800 in the UFW, is that necessary?

Just to be sure so that I do not have it allowed in UFW for nothing.

Comment: Only need that if you have the Firewall is enabled. Depending on the OS it might be enabled or not, Ubuntu for example don't have that enabled. You can try using `telnet` to quickly check if the port is available. `telnet <IP> 800`

Answer (score 1):

If this is for incoming SSH Connections, then yes, you would need to add a rule, as described in "[How To Set Up a Firewall with UFW on Ubuntu 18.04 / Step 3 — Allowing SSH Connections](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-allowing-ssh-connections)"

```
sudo ufw allow 800
```

Ideally, you can restrict that (as [seen here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands#allow-incoming-ssh-from-specific-ip-address-or-subnet)) to connections from a specific IP address or subnet

```
sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.0/24  to any port 800
```